# I am trying to perform mobile load testing using Jmeter but i receive 401 error in result tree

Tags: load-testing, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to load test my mobile application using jmeter, I have given authorization token in HTTP header manager and recorded the mobile app operations. But when I run this recorded script and view the result in result tree, all of the operations appear as failed and for some i see 401 un-authorization error. Please help me in solving this problem.
[This image shows the result I get after running the recorded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aPxG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP 401 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) means that you failed to provide correct credentials or token, you need either to login somehow or to pass a "good" token which your system expects.

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay recorded script without prior **correlation** - the process of extracting dynamic data from the previous response using a suitable [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), converting it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and adding it to the next request.

You can determine which parts of request are dynamic by recording the same actions once again and comparing the scripts. If there will be differences - you will need to handle the corresponding parameters.

Alternative option is using cloud-based proxy service for recording, it can export recorded requests in SmartJMX mode assuming automatic detection and correlation of any dynamic parameters. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more information.